# Create a short lived JMSProducer

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am using ActiveMQ5.10 and spring,

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="failover:(tcp://localhost:61616?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=120000)" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory"
    class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
    destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <ref local="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    </property>
    <property name="pubSubDomain" value="false" /> 
    <property name="deliveryMode" value="2" /> <!-- 2 implies persistent -->
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="false" />
    <property name="timeToLive" value="3600000" />
    <property name="explicitQosEnabled" value="true" />
</bean>
```

I need to create a producer which will send one message and then stop itself and then create new connection and send message again.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: what's the use case? A producer sends a message so it does not need to "stop" at all. Just use the `JmsTemplate` to send your message and you'll be fine unless I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: use case is producer send a message then it should close connection with ActiveMQ broker, after 1 minute (configurable), creates connection send message again and this cycle repeat.

Comment: I still don't get the problem. Just use the `JmsTemplate` to send your message. Have you tried?

Comment: (I have tried). I can send using jmstemplate, but after that how to close this connection, as I didn't create any connection explicitly.

Comment: Well you're using a `PooledConnectionFactory` so it may retain the actual connection to the broker for a little while but the whole point of `JmsTemplate` is that it will close things for you properly. What is this post exactly? Have you noticed a problem? If so, why don't you share it in your post?

Comment: I didn't noticed a problem, I am just trying to achieve a functionality, that it close connection and reconnect after 1 minute but I cant close application as such as I have other stat collection and all those going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that behavior for **all** producers and consumers, I think you'd get it from using a non-pooling connection factory, since each new message will cause a new connection to be created, used, and then torn down.  If you want that behavior for only some of them, make two connection factories (one pooled, one not) and two JMS templates (one using the pooled connection factory, one not), and have the clients use the appropriate JMS template.

Your performance would probably be terrible, but that should be OK because it sounds from the comments like this is an academic/esoteric problem (i.e. "I just want to see if I can figure out a way to do this, even though I don't have an actual reason I have to have it") rather than a real-world one.

Comment: I want it for ***some*** producer consumer and not ***all***

Comment: OK, so make two connection factories (one pooled, one not) and two JMS templates (one using the pooled connection factory, one not), and have the clients use the appropriate JMS template...